# intellij 2016 hangs when starting new gradle project w/ existing source

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, gradle

- i have some existing code (of which the language is irrelevant).
- i want to use intellij to debug some broken gradle tasks.
- we use gradle only as a build agent, nothing more.
- when trying to open the directory in intellij, it asks to import the project from gradle.

  - it then hangs indefinitely with the following progress bar. the task never completes.

i don't know how to begin troubleshooting it.  see attached img.

thanks!

[image]

Comment: Has the project already been opened once in Intelij at some point? My knee jerk advice is to stop using Intellij, but people seem to dislike that advice. Consider creating a new project, and moving your files over to the new project if nothing else works out.

Comment: No, fresh clone of the repository.  All I wanted out of intellij was the debug engine.  If you recommend another solution in order to debug a Gradle script, that would be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

i selected "use auto-import" and removed the "Gradle VM options" shown. not sure which did it, but that's all it took to resolve the issue.